# Cannot connect with psql to dockerized postgres

Tags: postgresql, docker

I'm having a problem connecting to a dockerized postgres

This is the container:

```
root@29de79c3cfa2:/# psql -U postgres -W
Password for user postgres: 
psql (9.5.14)
Type "help" for help.

postgres=#
```

From Mac terminal:

```
psql --host localhos -p 5234 -U postgres -W
Password for user postgres: 
psql: FATAL:  role "postgres" does not exist

$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES
29de79c3cfa2        postgres:9.5        "docker-entrypoint.s…"   14 minutes ago      Up 7 minutes        0.0.0.0:5234->5432/tcp   postgres_1
```

It seems ports match (I do get the connection on 5234), but for some reason it does not recognize the role? How can this be possible if ssh'ing into the container allows me to connect to with that role?

Comment: 0.0.0.0 isn't an IPv4 address you can connect to.  In the specific case where you're running this from the console, on the same host, using a "native" Docker solution (not Docker Toolbox), you can usually use `localhost` or 127.0.0.1.

Comment: Those don’t work either. The error says there’s no role anyway... the connection is good.

Answer (score 1):

It is working in my case. This is what I did

1. Run postgres docker image

   [root@yellowdog ]# docker run -d --name postgres -p 5432:5432 -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres postgres:9.5
   5bf259c6d3f8be43aa3dc2aed4496a4992a8d1ba5b999507652fd13fcc109c25
2. Test the working of postgres from docker container from a different postgresql container

   [root@yellowdog ]# docker run -it --rm --link postgres:postgres postgres psql -h postgres -U postgres

   Password for user postgres:

   psql (11.0 (Debian 11.0-1.pgdg90+2), server 9.5.14)

   Type "help" for help.

   postgres=# select 1;

   ### ?column?

   ```
       1
   ```

   (1 row)

   postgres=# \q
3. Finally test the working from host machine

   [root@yellowdog ]# psql -h localhost -U postgres

   Password for user postgres:

   psql (10.4, server 9.5.14)

   Type "help" for help.

   postgres=# select 1;

   ### ?column?

   ```
       1
   ```

   (1 row)

   postgres=# \q